# PHP update MySQL table with external values

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have a mysql table that is connected to xcode via php, Im trying to update a cell using this code, and is returning nothing in the table.

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
@mysql_select_db($db) or die("Unable to find database");

$routeID = $_GET["routeID"];
$newComment = $_GET["newComment"];

$query = "UPDATE routes SET comment = '$newComment' WHERE routeID='$routeID'";

mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error("error"));
mysql_close();
?>
```

If I changed `$routeID` to `routeID='routeID'` or `routeID=routeID` it would update the entire comment column and add the actual id into it e.g. `test?routeID=1`

If I changed `$routeID` to `routeID=1 or 20` etc. it would update the correct row. Any ideas on whats wrong with this.

Comment: you can get the mysql error, try to catch the error

Comment: Could you post the code that actually runs the query? Also, if `routeID` is a integer column you should not be quoting the value in the query.

Comment: The two paragraphs beneath your code are utterly indecipherable.

Comment: updated with the php file

Comment: @eggyal im retrieving `$routeID = $_GET["routeID"];` and `$newComment = $_GET["newComment"];` values from xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your querystring is currently `newComment=test?routeID=1`, whereas it *should* be `newComment=test&routeID=1`.<sup>*</sup>

Consequently, PHP parses the current querystring as a single name `newComment` with the value `test?routeID=1` rather than two names `newComment` and `routeID` with values `test` and `1` respectively.

However, please note that you absolutely **must not** simply concatenate values from the querystring directly into your SQL: so doing can lead to bugs if the values are not what was expected, which can be exploited by attackers to compromise your database.  See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496)

Please also note that, as documented under [`mysql_connect()`](http://php.net/mysql_connect):

> #### Warning
>
> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> - [mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)
> - [PDO::__construct()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

Finally, please note that the (optional) argument to [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) is the MySQL link identifier resource, `$conn` in your case: passing a string literal such as `"error"` will result in its failure.

<sup>* As documented under [Data Handling](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.data-handling), the default value for [`arg_separator.input`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.arg-separator.input) (which is described as "*List of separator(s) used by PHP to parse input URLs into variables.*") is `"&"`.  This is consistent with [the encoding used by browsers to submit form data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1), signified by the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` MIME type.</sup>

Comment: thanks for explaining, xcode was passing with `?` changed to a `&` and is working